# raising error does not prevent try-except clause to get executed?

Tags: python, exception, try-except, raise

I've got surprised while testing a piece of code that looked a bit like that:

```
if x:
    try:
           obj = look-for-item-with-id==x in a db
           if obj is None:
               # print debug message 
               raise NotFound('No item with this id')
           return obj
    except Exception, e:
        raise Error(e.message)
```

I expected that if there was no item with a provided id (x) in a db, the NotFound exception would be raised. But instead, after getting to if clause and  printing debug message it gets to the except clause and raises the Exception (exc message is Item not found...). Could someone be so kind and enlighten me here?

Comment: You're raising a `NotFound`, catching it, and then raising an `Error` instead. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: Ok, I get it now. The raise does not escape the clause but gets caught instead. Shame on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `except Exception, e:`, you are explicitly catching (almost) *any* exception that might get raised within that block -- including your `NotFound`.

If you want the `NotFound` itself to propagate further up, you don't need to have a `try/except` block at all.

Alternatively, if you want to do something specific when you detect the `NotFound` but then continue propagating the same exception, you can use a blank `raise` statement to re-raise it instead of raising a new exception like you're doing; something like:

```
try:
  # .. do stuff
  if blah:
    raise NotFound(...)
except NotFound, e: 
  # print something
  raise
```

Also note that I've changed the exception block to `except NotFound` -- it's generally not a good idea to use `except Exception` because it catches everything, which can hide errors you may not have expected. Basically, you want to use `except` to catch  *specific* things which you know how to handle right there.

Comment: I solved it like that: try: except NotFound: blah blah except Exception blah blah. What I wanted, was to check if the item was found - and if not, to RAISE NotFound and then, if it was not raised, check for all other problems (i know that Exception is too broad a term, it should probably be some db error in my case). My main mistake was to assume that raise NotFound would get raised as NotFound, kind of "breaking" out of the clause, not get caught and cause Error. I need to read more on exceptions. Anyway, I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

if obj is array please check if length or count of items is zero
this mean obj not none but not contain items

Comment: thanks, but obj is None... I've done some debugging on that

Comment: fanny is testing `if obj is None:`, not `if obj:`, so the "falsiness" of an empty list doesn't apply here.